# JS .children Returns an Object, Want an Array (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, children

According its [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp) (everyone's favorite resource, I know), the `.children` property returns

> A live HTMLCollection object, representing a collection of element
>   nodes

This object can be looped over as if it were an array like so:

```js
var elements = document.getElementById('test').children;

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  console.log(elements[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>paragraph 1</p>
  
  <p>paragraph 2</p>
  
  <p>paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

However attempting to use the `.map` function throws an error:

```js
var elements = document.getElementById('test').children;

var x = elements.map((element, index) => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>paragraph 1</p>

  <p>paragraph 2</p>

  <p>paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to get an array of child DOM elements, or do I have to loop through the object and manually create an array in order to use array methods like `.map()`? Note, I do not want to use jQuery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Array.from(elements)` P.S. Please oh _please_ don't use [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) as your reference!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `.map`?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts and believe me I have the same issues with w3schools as everyone else, however every other search result for .children discusses the jQuery method.

Comment: @putvande I need to convert the contents of a <div> to a JSON array

Comment: Cool, I was basing my searches around trying to find more information about .children, sorry for not searching htmlcollection. That question is 8 years old, however, and doesn't contain the ES6 solution that @SterlingArcher proposed, which I am going to use. Thanks for your help Patrick.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`.map` expects an array. You need to convert this array-like object (HTMLCollection) into a real array. There are several methods, but my 2 favorite are ES6 spread, and array from.

```
Array.from(document.getElementById('test').children).map
```

Or spreading

```
[...document.getElementById('test').children].map
```

If you don't want to use ES6, you can slice and force an array conversion, or `[].slice.call(document.getElementById('test').children)` I believe would also do a conversion.

As Patrick said in the comments: [].slice.call, not [].call. Might also want to mention the more wordy Array.prototype.slice.call since it doesn't initialize an unused empty array

The key here is that an HTMLCollection is an object, where `map` is an Array function.

Comment: Whoops, good catch!

Comment: Thanks for your help @SterlingArcher! I understand that it's not an array and that it needs to be converted. Do you know if there a difference in efficiency between `Array.from()` and the spread method? I am fine using ES6.

Comment: You could also use call on the map directly `Array.prototype.map.call( element.children, mappingFunction)`